# How to set position of text in TextView/EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

For example, lets say I have a for-loop and at every iteration(let's say for TextView t), I do t.setText(wordlist.get(i)). That just sets the value of the textview to whatever the last word in the list is. I want to set all the words next to each other. So what is the best way to do that?

Note: storing all the words in one big string is not an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `append` method of the textView. append all the string each iteration

**example:**

```
 t.append(wordlist.get(i));
```

Comment: Can I still do this with the SpannableStringBuilder class? like using SpannableStringBuilders instead of Strings ex: t.setText(SpannableStringBuilder);

Comment: @user3140562 you can do it but youll just gonna append and append each iteration.. to the SpannableStringBuilders

Answer (score 0):

why isnt it an option? for example take a look at this snippet:

```
String nums=""; for (int k=0;k<5;k++){
            if (milist[k][0].getNumber()<10){
                nums=nums+"0"+Integer.toString(milist[k][0].getNumber())+" ";
            }else{
            nums=nums+Integer.toString(milist[k][0].getNumber())+" ";}

                 } 
          tnums.setText(nums+"\n");
```

Comment: I'm using SpannableStringBuilders with Drawables so it's not that easy haha